# Leading "000" input in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
parseInt("09", 10) // 9 in this way it will just remove the leading 0
```

but i want to create a program that if the user input a number with leading zeros , the output will be invalid

Comment: Maybe just test with a regular expression for `/^0[^0]+$/`?

Comment: `if (string.substr(0, 1) == '0') // report invalid`

Comment: @Barmar That rejects `0` not just `01`.

Comment: @tadman So does your regexp.

Comment: @Barmar Just fixed it. Only realized when looking at your suggestion.

Comment: if `(string.substr(0, 1) == '0' && string.length > 2)` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(input) {
    return !/^0.*[0-9]/.test(input);
}

// false
console.log( test("01") );

// true
console.log( test("1") );

// false
console.log( test("00") );

// true
console.log( test("0") );
```

Answer (score 1):

// You can validate  '0', '0.2' or '2.00' with this regular expression:

```
function validDigits(str){
   return /^(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?$/.test(str)? 'valid':false;
}
```

//test:

```
['100', '1.0','0.5','05','0','2.0','002','2.00'].map(function(itm){
return itm+': '+ validDigits(itm);
}).join('\n')

/*  returned value: (String)
100: valid
1.0: valid
0.5: valid
05: false
0: valid
2.0: valid
002: false
2.00: valid
*/
```